# subquery with update laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I write simple query in mysql

```
 update cart set cart_price=(select sum(total_price) from cart_items where cart_id=9) where cart_id=9
```

I want to implement the same thing using Laravel elequent. How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query using `laravel query builder`.

```
DB::connection("YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME")
    ->table("cart")
    ->where('cart_id', 9)
    ->update([
        "cart_price" => DB::raw('(select sum(total_price) from cart_items where cart_id=9)')
    ]);
```

Comment: I am using this  `Cart::find($caritId)->update(["cart_price" =>DB::raw('select sum(total_price) from cart_items where cart_id=9')]);` but it giving me sql error

Comment: Error is `"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sum(total_price) from cart_items where cart_id=9, `updated_at` = ? where ' at line 1 (SQL: update `cart` set `cart_price` = select sum(total_price) from cart_items where cart_id=9, `updated_at` = 2016-05-19 09:48:51 where `cart_id` = 9)"`

Comment: just use `brackets` to wrap select statement in update function